# How to write an efficient divisibility test?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

The question in Python Koans specifies "Return True if any number in the list xs is divisible by 3. Otherwise, or if the list is empty, return False."

So far I've written `return any(x % 3 == 0 for x in xs)` but this only gives 2/3 stars.

Comment: is xs pre setup by you or not?is it generator or list?

Comment: Where's the `if the list is empty, return False` part to get your 3rd star?

Comment: I tried `return any(x % 3 == 0 for x in xs) if xs else False` but that was also 2/3 stars

Comment: FYI answer the was: `any(not x%3 for x in xs)`

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is not very efficient for large numbers. Maybe it's not fast enough?

For the special case of divisibility by three you can compute the sum of the digits in the number you are testing. If the sum is divisible by three, so is the number you started with.

For example

4789 => 4+7+8+9=28 => 2+8=10 => 1+0=1 (not divisible by three)

4788 => 4+7+8+8=27 => 2+7=9 (9 is divisible by three, and therefore 4788 is as well)

Comment: hmm.. that's right, basic math trick to check divisibility by 3. But how are you trying to extract digits from a number?

Comment: Well, there are several ways :)

You could do it like this 
    `(int(x) for x in str(4788))`

Comment: Well I don't know about python much, but they might be doing internally like mode 10 or divide 10 and that too in a loop. is it more efficient than a single mode by 3? unless the number is really huge that we are storing it in an array or string, in which case we will be accessing digits via index.

Comment: Division is a much more expensive operation than addition. So this method is more efficient. But it will only be noticeable for very large numbers. I don't know what data you are working on so I can't tell you if the difference will be significant or not.

Comment: one test case is a list of (0,1,2,...9)

Comment: Storing the number or string in memory is not your bottleneck though

Comment: On that data the speedup is not noticable

Comment: for sure addition is much faster than division. But my question is have you thought about how internally your script is fetching digits from a number? is it not using multiple divisions and modes? in that case, are those multiple divisions better than a single division?